# issue testing push notification with a distribution certificate

Tags: ios, push-notification, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I am following this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Now with development certificate works fine, but I'm getting crazy to test with the distribution certificate!

I did the same thing only using the .p12 and the relative distribution certificate instead of development, but that will never get the notifications!

Maybe I'm missing something .. could someone kindly explain how you can test push with the distribution certificate?

The app is already on App Store.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I solved it by creating an ad-hoc distribution, but now I have another problem:

**if i test my php code from terminal in my desktop everything works fine. but if I try to upload php and .pem file to my server, the push notification stop to work!!!**

maybe I change the path of ck.pem in php code?

Comment: Could you please provide the full source code for the php script sending notifications?

Comment: @NikolayMamaev now i think the problem is to get the device token for distribution... but i don't know how

Comment: The device token should be generated by call of the `[UIApplication registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:]` method and sent to your server, there are no any tricks here. It only matters which kind of certificate was used to sign a build which generates a device token. That is:
- If device token is generated & sent to server by a build signed by your development cert, then the php script should use a dev cert & gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195.
- If device token is generated by a build signed by distribution cert, then the php script should use a distribution cert & gateway.push.apple.com:2195

Comment: @NikolayMamaev yes you're right, now i'm trying to create ad-hoc and test if without .sandbox the push works

Comment: @NikolayMamaev and that's it! creating ad-hoc the device token is different from what I was using, and so now this works! thanks for suggestion!

Comment: I'm glad to help you! It would be nice if you vote for the comment. Thanks!

Comment: @NikolayMamaev ok now i have other problem.. if i test php code in my desktop is all right.. but if i try from my server i got error!!!

Comment: Unfortunately details you've provided are not enough to understand what's wrong; besides it, your new problem has a different nature than the original question, so perhaps it makes sense to create a new question with detailed description of your new problem.

Answer (score 1):

For production environment, please use `gateway.push.apple.com:2195` push notification server in the simplepush.php (instead of `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195`). Please see the [Provider Communication with Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html) article for more information.